# CROW notation for ER diagram SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, entity-relationship, erd

I am new to Oracle SQL Developer tool.
I see Entity diagrams in CROW notation.

How to represent uni-directional and bi-directional relationships in CROW notation?

Is it like the usual --> for uni and --- for bi w.r.t Oracle SQL Developer?

and what does dashed and solid line interpret? Is it strong vs weak relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Notations supported include Barker, Bachman, and Information Engineering

Make sure you have Notation set to Barker

Right click on the diagram...

[image]

I believe the dashed lines mean the relationships are non-identifying.